# How to dynamic use SqlFunctions.PatIndex

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I need to use SqlFunctions.PatIndex in expression.

```
Func<IQueryable<T>, KendoFilterDescription, IQueryable<T>> appendFilter =
                (filteredData, filter) => filteredData.Where(String.Format("System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.PatIndex(\"@0\", {0})", filter.Field), ParsePropertyValue(filter));
```

but I get an exception: `No property or field 'System' exists in type 'RecordListItem'`

How to use this function?

Comment: Can you ellaborate on what you are trying to accomplish? Didn't this work for you: `(filteredData, filter) => filteredData.Where(f => System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.PatIndex("@0", "") != 0);`

Comment: @Mediator: When asking a question, especially if it is not that clearly phrased, it would would be helpful if you could at least respond to people who took the effort to provide you with an answer and asked for clarification on what you are trying to achieve. Could you please do so.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the long expression in your code example it is probably difficult to see, but it appears the "Where" clause contains an error, in that it is not an expression that can be reduced to a `Func<T, bool>`.

I am assuming this is why you are getting a compiler error. Without any more information on what `KendoFilterDescription` is, what `ParsePropertyValue` does and what you are trying to filter on using `PatIndex` it is difficult to come up with a good answer for you.

So for now I will try a wild guess:

1. You are trying to filter the IQueryable using a PatIndex expression.
2. If the evaluated PatIndex expression does not return 0, the "Where" should evaluate to true, so the record is included in the result.
3. You want the `stringPattern` argument for the PatIndex expression to be equal to the return value of `ParsePropertyValue(filter)`, i.e. the pattern to be matched.
4. You want the `target` argument for the PatIndex expression to be equal to the value of the property or field of `T` with the name `filter.Field`.

So as an example, let's take a class Person (T) with a property FirstName and LastName. And suppose you wish to filter on FirstName's containing a certain phrase, then you would want to build an expression like:

```
Func<string, string> BuildContainsPattern = phrase => string.Format("%{0}%", phrase);
Func<IQueryable<Person>, string, IQueryable<Person>> whereFirstNameContains =
            (data, phrase) => data.Where(p => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(BuildContainsPattern(phrase), p.FirstName) > 0);
```

Assuming this is (basically) correct. We need a few building blocks, that together allow us to build an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` that can be passed to the `Where` clause of the `IQueryable<T>`.

Ok, so the difficult part first. The `BuildFilterExpression` function below can build this expression for us, provided that we supply it with (1) the `stringPattern` that is expected as the first argument for the `PatIndex` function and (2) the name of the property on entity type `T` that we wish to use as the second argument to the `PatIndex` function.

So if my assumptions on what `ParsePropertyValue(filter)` and `filter.Field` represent were correct, the code below should do the filtering, using the settings supplied by the filter.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Data.Objects.SqlClient;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

public class FilterDescription
{
    public enum FilterPatternType
    {
        Contains = 1,
        Range = 2, // [^0-9]
    }
    public string Field { get; set; }
    public string FilterPhrase { get; set; }
    public FilterPatternType PatternType { get; set; }
}

public static class FilterBuilder
{
    private static readonly MethodInfo PatIndexMethod = typeof(SqlFunctions).GetMethod("PatIndex");
    private static readonly ConstantExpression ValueZero = Expression.Constant(0, typeof(int?));

    public static string ParsePropertyValue(FilterDescription filter)
    {
        switch (filter.PatternType)
        {
            case FilterDescription.FilterPatternType.Contains:
                return string.Format("%{0}%", filter.FilterPhrase);
            case FilterDescription.FilterPatternType.Range:
                return string.Format("[^{0}]", filter.FilterPhrase);
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Pattern type not supported");
        }
    }

    public static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> BuildFilterExpression<TEntity>(string patternString, string targetProperty)
    {
        var patternStringArg = Expression.Constant(patternString);
        var entityType = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "item");
        var targetPropertyArg = Expression.PropertyOrField(entityType, targetProperty);

        MethodCallExpression patIndexCall = Expression.Call(PatIndexMethod, patternStringArg, targetPropertyArg);

        var isGreaterThanZero = Expression.GreaterThan(patIndexCall, ValueZero);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(isGreaterThanZero, entityType);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> BuildFilterExpression<TEntity>(FilterDescription filter)
    {
        var pattern = ParsePropertyValue(filter);
        return BuildFilterExpression<TEntity>(pattern, filter.Field);
    }

    public static IQueryable<TEntity> Filter<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> toFilter, FilterDescription filter)
    {
        return toFilter.Where(BuildFilterExpression<TEntity>(filter));
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    private static IQueryable<Person> GetPersons()
    {
        return (IQueryable<Person>)null; // use your own data.
    }

    public static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        var filter = new FilterDescription() 
        { 
            PatternType = FilterDescription.FilterPatternType.Contains,
            Field = "FirstName",
            FilterPhrase = "ed"
        };
        var filtered = GetPersons().Filter(filter);
    }
}
```

Obviously it is possible that I completely got my wild guess wrong, but then I suppose you will improve your description of what you are trying to achieve.